# how can I disable this sound notifications

Tags: 19.10

[Annoying Audio Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUzT5.jpg)

I have this Audio notification showing up every time I get a new message, or new email or what ever that triggers an audio notification. Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- Open **Settings**
2- Go to **Notifications** panel
3- select/click on the application that annoys you by its notifications.
You will get a window like the following:

[image]

4- To disable the sound notifications, turn **Sound Alerts** off.
5- If you want to disable the notification from appearing, turn **Notification Popups** off.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for thanks, there is way to many things these days that I sometimes I get lost LOL